# Get the selected values in a datagrid with material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a datagrid with several elements and I would like to retrieve the checked datas.
I saw in the element document that there is a controlled selection but I can't get it to work.
I'll put my current code below, thanks in advance!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
    { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
    { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
    {
      field: 'age',
      headerName: 'Age',
      type: 'number',
      width: 90,
    },
    {
      field: 'fullName',
      headerName: 'Full name',
      description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
      sortable: false,
      width: 160,
      valueGetter: (params) =>
        `${params.getValue('firstName') || ''} ${
          params.getValue('lastName') || ''
        }`,
    },
  ];
  
  const rows = [
    { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
    { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
    { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
    { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
    { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null },
    { id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 },
    { id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 },
    { id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 },
    { id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 },
  ];

export default function App() {
    const [select, setSelection] = React.useState([]);
    return (
        <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid 
                rows={rows} 
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={25}
                checkboxSelection 
                hideFooterPagination 
                onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
                    setSelection(newSelection.rows);
                }}
            />
            <h1>{select}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you log your `select` state you can see that the state is being set according to what is selected. `onSelectionChange` callback `newSelection` parameter already contains what you seek.

[image]

The main issue with your code is `<h1>{select}</h1>`. While `select` is indeed an array and arrays are valid React children, each of your array element contains an object (e.g., `firstName`, `lastName`), therefore it won't work with that setup.

[image]

You may iterate over the array and print each individual array element object property value.

Example below is printing out `firstName`:

```
return (
  <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
    <h1>{select.map((val) => val.firstName)}</h1>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={25}
      checkboxSelection
      hideFooterPagination
      onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
        setSelection(newSelection.rows);
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: When I do that, it keeps re-rendering because onSelectionChange is triggered on its own when the component renders. So when I setSelection and the component re-renders, onSelectionChange is fired and causes a re-render. And keeps on re-rendering... Any help? Thanks

Comment: you mean an infinite loop? looks ok on my side https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-antonelli-05rtr?file=/src/App.js. as a side note, the only thing I changed on your code is literally the child of `h1` and where `h1` is rendered. any pre-existing issues your code base has was not caused by this update

Comment: instead it is `onSelectionModelChange` not `onSelectionChange`

Answer (score 5):

The documentation was updated, and I updated this example: [answer from this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64420757/15112403), now according to the documentation `selectionModel` contains an array of `id` selected rows

[image: Edit unruffled-hawking-8kez0]

Comment: Super helpful. This is the clearest answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could start by getting total rows `onRowSelected`, or from the context on some other event method by stepping into the api a bit. This is as of 03/2020, but I found nothing on this in the API docs:
`onRowSelected={(x) => x.api.current.getSelectedRows()}`, on DataGrid `"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.22"` works for me. I can do everything I need from this in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
    <h1>{select.map((val) => val.firstName)}</h1>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={25}
      checkboxSelection
      hideFooterPagination
      onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
        setSelection(newSelection.rows);
      }}
    />
  </div>
);

<https://mui.com/components/data-grid/selection/#heading-controlled-selection>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Summarisation of the ans from @95faf8e76605e973 and comment from @abderrezague mohamed for anyone want to copy and paste

```
return (
  <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
    <h1>{select.map((val) => val.firstName)}</h1>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={25}
      checkboxSelection
      hideFooterPagination
      onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionArray) => {
        // newSelectionArray is [5,1] given the select order is 5 then 1
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
      setSelection(newSelection.rows);
}} 

to
onRowSelectionModelChange={(newSelection) => {
      setSelection(newSelection.rows);
}}
```